# rails email notification- mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailer

I'am new to rails. Users need to receive the email notification after few days only if they haven't read the notification yet. I've created the email notification with Action Mailer but it's not working after added the time format. The email still not deliver to the users after 5 days.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

 def show
  @notification = current_user.notifications.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if current_user.notifications.unread > 5.days.ago
   UserMailer.try_notif(@notification, @post, @user).deliver
  end
 end

 def update
  @notification = current_user.notifications.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @notification.update(read: true)
  redirect_to post_path(@notification.post)
 end

 def read_all
  current_user.notifications.unread.update_all(read: true)
 end
end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

 def try_notif(notification, post, user)
  @notification = notification
  @post = post
  @user = user
  mail(to: @post.user.email, subject: 'New Notification')
 end
end
```

Comment: what error you are getting? and check `current_user.notifications.unread` returns the date, else the comparision fails

Comment: What is the expected workflow? At the moment a mail is send in the moment a user looks at one specific notification. If he doesn't look at the notifications he will not get that email at all. Furthermore if he is already looking at the notification, what is the point of sending him an email about the notification?

Comment: I didn't receive the email when I tried with changing the 5.days.ago to 5.minutes.ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think correct code would be like this:
Need to check each notification with current time

```
if current_user.notifications.unread
  current_user.notifications.each do |notification|
   if Time.current - notification.created_at > 120  #just checking in hours
    #send reminder
   end
  end
end
```

or can try other way

```
@notifications = Notification.where(created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.current, unread: true)
if @notifications 
  @notifications.each do |notification|
   #send notification
  end
end
```

Comment: You can make the modification in the second example to .. current_user.notifications.where(..)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Btw, still didn't receiving the email.